# Unable to tar a .tgz file

Tags: nvidia, software-installation, tar

I have a .tgz file and I'm running `tar -xfvz cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz` but that I get the following error:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I don't understand why this is happening. I got the the file using the following curl command: `curl -O https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/v7.0.5/prod/9.0_20171129/cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz`

Perhaps this is a problem with `curl`? I tried using `wget` but that doesn't even get the file for some reason.

What am I doing wrong?

With the command: `tar -xfz cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz` I get the following error:

```
tar: z: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: Try to swap the order of the options. I think `f` should be followed directly by the file name, `tar -xvzf cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz`

Comment: Just tried it. Same problem

Comment: Try without the option `z`. I think for extraction, it will find the compression method automatically; it might not be what you think from the extension.

Comment: Still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Is there any published checksum, for example `md5sum`? In that case you can check if the file was downloaded correctly.

Comment: No, I don't see any checksum for this file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your answer is simple, that file doesn't exists and `curl` just save a HTML document as a `.tgz` file!

You can check it by opening [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/v7.0.5/prod/9.0_20171129/cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz) link in your browser. As you see, *Page Not Found!*

Also you can check it by command line:

```
curl -Is https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/v7.0.5/prod/9.0_20171129/cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz | head -n 1
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

As you can see, it has the same output.

So when you run this command:

```
curl -O https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/v7.0.5/prod/9.0_20171129/cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz
```

Curl just download this web page and save it as `.tgz` file. So you can change `.tgz` suffix to `.html` and open that file with favorite web browser like firefox, because its not in gzip format it is just a HTML document.

Also when we check `cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz` file format, as you see it is `HTML document` and it's not `gzip compressed data`:

```
file cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz 
cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

---

**Update:**

For download `cudnn` you can visit [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download) page, and after logging in, you can find many versions of `cuddn` that you can download them.

And [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/v7.0.5/prod/9.0_20171031/cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7) is exactly the same file with which one, you want to download it before (But now many new versions and easy install files like `.deb` are available and you can download them instead).

---

**Update2**:

Because you said, you can't access web browser, I got [this](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/cudnn/v7.0.5/cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz) download link and write this command:

```
curl -O http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/cudnn/v7.0.5/cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz
```

So you can use it by command line without web browser or logging in.

Comment: Then how else would I download the file? I noted in the question that wget didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps I can save it in google drive using another machine and download it that way?

Comment: I am unable to find any good links to cudnn downloads

Comment: That's exactly the page and link I used though.

Comment: I can go into a browser because I'm hooking into a remote cluster. There is no gui desktop on that environment.

Comment: I meant to say "I can't* go into a broswer"

Comment: The 2nd update worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As per this [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/169195/tar-exiting-with-failure-status-due-to-previous-errors?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) answer:

> If you are using the `-v` flag, try leaving it off. This should reduce
>   the output and let you see what is going on.

I'll see if I can find a better link. In the meantime change your command to:

```
tar -xfz cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz
```

Now you can see all the error messages. Then adjust your question accordingly or answer your own question using the new information.

Comment: With that command, I go back to my previous error. @AliRazmdideh

Comment: @Jonathan confirm the file exists with `locate cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz`

Answer (score 0):

The `f` option specifies the file, so you must provide the file name right after the `f` option (order matters in this case):

Also the file is not compressed so remove the `z` option

```
tar -xvf cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.tgz
```

Comment: See comments from question

Comment: Still nope. Doesn't work.